# How to get the name of Telegram bot with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a custom management system for Telegram bots so that I can be able to send and read updates easily.. But my main problem is that I don't know how to retrieve data from an array. let me explain this in depth so you can understand what I'm talking about.

Basically when I try the `getme` command, I get this:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"id":275700102,"first_name":"photoshop_post_production","username":"post_pro_bot"}}
```

So I converted this into an array using Php and it goes like this:

```
$_SESSION['website'] = "https://api.telegram.org/bot";
$_SESSION['url'] = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$_SESSION['token'];

$_SESSION['me'] = file_get_contents($_SESSION['url']."/getme");
$_SESSION['meArray'] = json_decode($_SESSION['me'], TRUE);
```

So as you can see I have an array called `meArray` and if I `print_r` it ,this will be shown:

```
Array ( [ok] => 1 [result] => Array ( [id] => 275700102 [first_name] => photoshop_post_production [username] => post_pro_bot ) )
```

So basically I don't know how to take out the username or other information that I want from this array. I have tried several things but no success till now.

Comment: Take a quick look at almost any question in the JSON tag and you should get an answer

Comment: PHP is very array oriented, its the second thing you need to become familiar with once you have learned to spell PHP [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, should be:

**`$_SESSION['meArray']['result']['username']`**

Try this.

Comment: Thats not gonna work if u mean this: $_SESSION['username'] = $_SESSION['meArray']['username'];

Comment: Oh is true. I had noticed that he was saving the result in $_SESSION. 
However, it should be $_SESSION['meArray']['result']['username'] considering the print_r result...

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit your answer and add the correct syntax, so other do not have to look at the comments to find the correct answer

Comment: Done! I'm a newbie on StackOverflow :)